# delete object from a nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a nested object of this structure.

```
mainObject: {
   1: {
         id: 1,
         name:'alpha'
      },
   2: {
         id: 2,
         name:'beta'
      },
   3: {
         id: 3,
         name:'gamma'
        
      }
}
```

i want to delete on object from this ,say 1 but that in an immutable way . I tried the following code.

```
    const list =Object.values(mainObject)
    const newList=list.filter((item)=>{item.id!=1})
    newList.forEach((item)=>{
        mainObject[item.id]={
          id: item.id,
          name:item.name
        }
    })
```

this is not working .What am i doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, `delete mainObject[1]` doesn't work?

Comment: it is working but immutability is required

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the object with the id of 1, or the object at key 1?

Comment: explain what you mean by immutability in this context - by the way `const newList=list.filter((item)=>{item.id!=1})` will ALWAYS be an empty list since your callback doesn't return anything

Comment: object at key 1

Comment: `mainObject[item.id]={
          id: item.id,
          name:item.name
        }` - sets the value to exactly what it was .... and ignores the "deleted" key, keeping it at what it was ... so, in essence, your code will always do exactly nothing interesting - seriously, even if your code did what you expected, it would change the content of `mainObject` - so ... what do you mean by immutably

Comment: If I get you right, why not just set the object at key 1 to null or undefined, mainObject[1] = null;

Comment: no i want to delete it completely.. because i need the count of the objects somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use destruct assignment for deletion

```
const { 1: _, ...newObject } = mainObject
```

```js
const mainObject = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "alpha",
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "beta",
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: "gamma",
  },
}

const { 1: _, ...newObject } = mainObject

console.log(mainObject)
console.log(newObject)
```

Or clone `mainObject` in to an different object then apply deletion

```
const newObject = { ...mainObject }
delete newObject[1]
```

```js
const mainObject = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "alpha",
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "beta",
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: "gamma",
  },
}

const newObject = { ...mainObject }
delete newObject[1]

console.log(mainObject)
console.log(newObject)
```

Or transform object into array of key-value pairs, reject your delete pair and then transform it back to object

```
const newObject = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(mainObject).filter(([key]) => key !== "1")
)
```

```js
const mainObject = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "alpha",
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "beta",
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: "gamma",
  },
}

const newObject = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(mainObject).filter(([key]) => key !== "1")
)

console.log(mainObject)
console.log(newObject)
```

---

**Reference**

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

[Object.prototype.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

[Object.prototype.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: note, in both cases `newObject` is a *shallow copy*

Comment: my key  needs to be a number ..can it be modified

Comment: @Deepakmaurya this part `key !== "1"`?

Comment: yes my key is a number so in side newObject i need it as a number @hgb123

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` operator and `spread` syntax to achieve what you want.
For the object you have mentioned, let me walk you through it.

```
const mainObject = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'alpha',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'beta',
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'gamma',
  },
};

const newObj = { ...mainObject};
delete newObj["1"];
```

Read More on Spread syntax on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Read More on `delete` operator on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Hope it helps

```js
const mainObject = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'alpha',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'beta',
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'gamma',
  },
};
const newObj = { ...mainObject};
delete newObj["1"];

document.write(`<p>mainObject:</p> <pre> ${JSON.stringify(mainObject)} </pre>`)
document.write(`<p>newObj:</p> <pre> ${JSON.stringify(newObj)} </pre>`)
```